# Why are my potted outdoor Plumeria leaves turning yellow and brown?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, containers

All the leaves are yellow, with red around the edges and then eventually start turning brown?

Comment: Welcome Lynn! Would you please add some pictures of your plant, and give us some more details? Have you recently moved it, or changed the care? Has the temperature changed? Did it just start happening? Do the leaves have any holes? Do you see any insects? I know this is a lot, but the more we know, the better we can help you! When you answer this, just put the information in the question itself, by using [edit]. Thanks!

Comment: How long have you had this plant? Have you had it over the winter in the past? (assuming you are in the northern hemisphere).